# How to correctly check if a token exists in the store before redirecting

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

In my application, I want to check if a token exists for the user and, based on this, redirect them somewhere. I have defined the code as follows:

```
componentDidMount() {
    SecureStore.getItemAsync('token').then((val) => {
        val ? Actions.link() : null
    }
    ).then(this.setState({ loaded: true }))
}
```

However, Actions.link() is never called even though the value does exist and can be logged to the console.

How does one correctly check whether a variable exists or not?

Comment: What's showing if you output  `console.log(val)` ?

Comment: fa1306ad7bc6e7215a6ad7bc6ebc6e7215a06ad7

Comment: Try to add a `debugger` statement and see where you go. Are you sure you're not entering `Actions.link`, or could it be that you don't enter the second `then` ?

Comment: Thanks youre spot on there, it was exactly that - not entering Actions.link()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might have something to do with the short if/else

can you try:

```
if (val) {
    Actions.link()
}
```